# Coupon + other cart price rules

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, coupon, magento-2.0.4

So i am trying to set up a coupon code. But whenever i use the coupon code in my cart it overrides the other cart price rules.

For example :

i have a rule when a product is ordered by 6 pcs they get 10% discount on that product.
When i use my coupon code that is overruled.

Settings :
Coupon code :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear i'm searching for a way to add the coupon discount to the current discounts that already work instead of replacing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the code from https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2931

Hope this helps :)